# Need to make POST request through robot framework with Upload File option

Tags: python-3.x, rest, curl, post, robotframework

I have a requirement to send a POST request through robot framework. I am able to successfully run the post request through postman tool. Below is the curl command which is generated through postman tool:

curl --location --request POST 'https://ip/abc/rest/api/v1/VNF/fdnid/Tasks' \
--form 'ParamsFile=@/C:/Users/vr98.json'

Key is provided as ParamsFile and file : vr98.json is selected.

How can i achieve same functionality in ROBOT?
I have tried below code, but it does not seem to work

VF Tasks

```
${Header}    Set Variable    {"Authorization": "Bearer ${nsp_token}", "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}
create session  VF  ${BASE_URL}${NFVServer_URL}  headers=${Header}
${file}=    Evaluate    ("ParamsFile":"C:/Users/vr98.json")           
${response}=    post request    VF    VNF/fdnid/Tasks    files=${file}
should be equal as strings  ${response.status_code}  200*
```